# Get full text of a direct message with 140+ characters with the Twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

Is it possible to get the full text of a Twitter direct message which is longer than 140 characters?

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/show.json?id=...
```

The field "text" of the response is truncated and doesn't show the full text.

```
"text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et ... [LINK TO THE DM]"
```

I tried adding "tweet_mode=extended" to the URL, but that doesn't have any effect on direct messages.

Is there a different way to get the untruncated text?

Answer (score 0):

> Send “full_text=true” as a query parameter to receive long DM text. If
>   this parameter is not provided, you will get a truncated version of
>   the DM. There will be no structural changes to the response returned
>   by these endpoints.

Source: https://twittercommunity.com/t/removing-the-140-character-limit-from-direct-messages/41348